# How to cause a Control follow its DataSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, datasource

At the beginning, when I assign my collection to a control's DataSource, it follows what is in the collection. During the execution of my program, when the collection changes, I don't see any change in the control's content. How can I make the control follow the latest changes of the collection?

What I have is:

```
private void FormEditImages_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    radListView1.DataSource = WebServiceHelper.Instance.CurrentSession.Images;
    radListView1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    radListView1.ValueMember = "Id";
}

private void radListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var cameraOverlayImage = e.Item.DataBoundItem as CameraOverlayImage;
    e.Item.Image = CreateThumbnail(cameraOverlayImage.Image, e.ListViewElement.ItemSize.Width - 12, e.ListViewElement.ItemSize.Height - 16, e.ListViewElement.BackColor);
    e.Item.TextAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    e.Item.TextImageRelation = TextImageRelation.ImageAboveText;
    e.Item.ImageAlignment = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
}
```

How can I change the ItemDataBound method when I change Load to:

```
private void FormEditImages_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var bindingSource = new BindingSource(WebServiceHelper.Instance.CurrentSession.Images, "Name");
    radListView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
}
```

Comment: Use the `BindingSource` as `DataSource` and assign your collection to it's `DataSource`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/raise-change-notifications--bindingsource

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I updated the question to include the next step.